# Changing default caption name in table environment

Tags: tables, environments, babel, polish

I am using a polish latex package and I noticed something weird.

When I begin the table environment the caption normally (in English) begins with Table 1: {title}

In Polish, it begins with `Tablica 1`. This is really weird because Table does not translate into `Tablica` it translates into `Tabela`.
I would like to change the table environment to say Tabela instead of Tablica.
I have no idea how to do that. I read about `\captionof` but I'd like to continue using the table environment.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering\captionsetup{font=small}
    \caption{Przyporządkowanie obiektów modelu logicznego i fizycznego}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
       \toprule
       \textbf{Obiekty modelu logicznego} & \textbf{Obiekty 
       modelu fizycznego} \\ 
       \midrule
        Encja & Tabela \\[0.2cm]
        Atrybut encji & Kolumna tabeli \\[0.2cm]
        Identyfikator encji & Klucz główny tabeli \\[0.2cm]
        Związek & Klucz obcy i reguły integralności \\
        \bottomrule\addlinespace[0.5ex]
    \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\footnotesize Źródło: Czapla K., Bazy danych. Podstawy projektowania i języka SQL, 2015}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

This code creates something like this.

[image]

Basically, I would like to change `Tablica 1` to `Tabela 1` while still using the environment so the changes would apply to all other tables

Edit:
I started to wonder if making my own new numbered environment isn't the solution for me. I would like to hear an opinion from more experienced users than myself

Comment: Assuming that you are using the `babel` package you can use `\addto\captionspolish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela}}`

Comment: Worked like a charm